# Extractor installer

Tags: nsis

I created an installer with version NSIS_2.46.5 and it cannot be extracted with Universal Extractor software. But when I open the installer with the hexadecimal editor program like the image below and delete a byte from the first line, the installer is easily extracted. How can I prevent this? Do I need to add strings to the script or use custom software when compiling? I thank and appreciate any help and guidance

[image: binary data]

Answer (score 1):

NSIS is open source so there is not much you can do to prevent unpacking of installers made with the official compiler.

If you want to stop generic tools, reorder the `EW_...` entries in \Source\exehead\fileform.h and compile NSIS yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but it's very complicated. Do you know anyone who would do this for me and create a custom nsis and get paid for it?

Comment: Yes it is a bit complicated. Worrying about pirates is pointless, they will get your files no matter what you do...

Comment: Yes you are right . I just want the file extraction to be a little complicated and people with programs like Universal Extractor not able to extract it? I recently found a site called http://9649.ru that creates portable applications and their portable applications can not be extracted even by removing one byte of the program. I do not know what method they use?

Comment: I just want the installer not to be so easy to extract and a little complicated